# .load callback has been called five times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

The code I am using is shown below, I am pretty sure I am missing a point but could not find out.

What I am doing is, when user press the button, a fragment of the page has been `load`ed. After successful loading I need to do some business(just once ofc.), unfortunately, callback function seems to be called exactly 5 times. I have tried basic google solutions but no chance. Thanks in advance.

```
val = 1;
$( "#signup" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( ".container" ).load("/signup", function(event) {
        console.log("val: "+val);
        val++;
     });
});
```

and the console log shows

```
val: 1
val: 2
val: 3
val: 4
val: 5
```

PS: I am not sure if it is related or not but the project also uses `laravel` and `bootstrap`.

Comment: Do you have 5 elements on the page with a "container" class?

Comment: why are you defining `load` event in `$( "#signup" ).click` handler?

Comment: @MattS the only container is an empty div:  `    <div class="container">
    </div>`

Comment: @Mritunjay I need to load some web content on a button click, are there some other problematic things which I also missed?

Comment: Maybe similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463500/load-callback-has-been-called-five-times. Are you running this click handler everytime new load is completed.

Comment: @vishwanath can u update the link please...

Comment: Update what? does this answer your question...

Comment: @vishwanath the link points this question, so they are more than similar :)   Tho, I am sure event.preventDefault(); is called once.

Comment: event.preventDefault() doesnt unregister the previous events. It just prevents the standard action browser takes for the event. Eg Submitting form in case of submit event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't you have many '.container' in your html ? log $( ".container" ) for checking

Comment: what I getting is `Object { 0: <div.container>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → artisan.url, selector: ".container" }`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @bitoiu I agree with you, on the other hand, it helped me find out some secret third party `container`s in my code.

Comment: arf too funny, so always double check your html content, and maybe post it with the question ;) but its bizarre, your log seems saying there was only one element...but maybe what is loaded contains some .containers... ?